# Can only read value from spring boot's application.property file in debug mode when running the tests

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I have a spring boot 2.7 kotlin application where the tests can only read the values from the property file when I run the tests in debug mode, in normal mode when I just Run the tests I get the error that says the username should not be empty. The application is using the `@Value` annotation to read the property and  the

`@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")`

is also added. This is how I am using the `@Value`

```
@Service
class MyService(
@Value("\${Something.username}") private val user: String,
@Value("\${Something.password}") private val pwd: String,
@Value("\${accesstoken.endpoint}") val tokenEndpoint: String
) {
  ......
}
```

cheers,

es

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has the same problem they should add the

```
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
```

to their tests. This fixed the problem for me and I can run the tests now using the Run test command or with `mvn test` command.

Why this works and adding the

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
```

to the main class does not is still a mistery for me?